What's the proper way to conclude the OAuth2 flow in Django?
To keep the story short, I've acquired all the necessary tokens from Google using the "auth code" flow.
So currently, I have the following tokens at my disposal:
1. access_token
2. refresh_token
3. id_token
4. verified JWT token

The next step is to log in the user using the provided login() method from django.contrib.auth. This creates a sessionId which is then used to "verify" that a user is logged in.
In my current development setup, I'm just using the email from the JWT token to create the session:
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def login_provider(request):
    # 1. Get the user info from JWT token (assume I have it)
    user_obj = jwt_token.user
   
    # 2. Create a Django user instance
    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(email=user_obj.email)
    
    # 3. Log the user in
    login(request, user)
    
    # 4. Redirect the user somewhere else
    return redirect("somewhere-else/")

I've taken all the necessary steps to ensure the Google OAuth2 flow part is secure but am I correct in assuming that this way of logging the user in isn't secure since I'm basically using just the users email?
What's the correct way to do this?
